# Connect website form to (compiled) java / common lisp program (website as UI)

Tags: javascript, java, php, backend

### What I know    (with regard to what might be relevant to my problem)

Java, some Common Lisp, HTML5 and basic JavaScript.

### What I have so far

- Two finished programs, one written in Java and one written in Common Lisp.
  (which both parse an input string from the prompt or a file and, if valid, do some calculations and return a result string.)
- A rudimentary Website (on a freehoster) including some text input forms and submit buttons.

#### What I'd like to know

**Is it possible (and if so: *how*?) to connect my website to my (compiled) programs?**

**More precisely:**
I want to offer the functionality of my programs to visitors of my website.
As you can guess the visitor should be able to enter the data in a text field (e.g. a `<textarea>`), submit it and my website sends/feeds the data to my program to process it.
The output of the program should then be displayed on the website.

I thought this would be a pretty ordinary task but googling it just left me confused and disillusioned. (It seems I have to do something "on the server-side", use PHP and frameworks and what not.)

#### I just don't know what to do next.

Maybe I'm searching with the wrong target words (english not being my mother tongue) or maybe I just can't see the wood for the trees, but I'm a bit lost and it don't know where to go next. Learn php? Read about "server-side"? Familiarize myself with framework foo?
**Therefore I would be really grateful for some clear advice on how to proceed from here, i.e.: How do I connect those different worlds (my basic website with the funcionality of my programs)?**

- What is my next step?
- Does someone happen to know a good book / tutorial / youtube video regarding this next step?
- Or, if this is asking too much (if so, I apologize, but I simply don't know how small or big the problem is that I am describing) maybe some keywords to point me in the right direction so that I can google "tutorial for foo" or "book on bar" 
  (so that I know I'm getting somewhere when I work through this tutorial/book).

I very much appreciate any concrete help.

Comment: See https://github.com/fukamachi/clack

Comment: Looks interesting. Will give it a try. (But seems sparsely documented.)

Comment: Have you asked the authors of the repository for links to further documentation?

Comment: No, I didn't. I followed the documentation link to quickdocs.org/clack/ that seems to provide the same 2 examples as github plus an api reference (which is something).

Answer (score 1):

A PHP page can run external applications, so if your programs can be run from a terminal session / shell you can probably get them to run in PHP.

You can use the exec() command, see the PHP manual page for it -  http://php.net/manual/en/function.exec.php

```
echo exec('whoami');
```

Or you can build a command line and run that through the shell using backticks  (``) or shell_exec like this:

```
$zip_cmd = "zip -D $tmp_folder$zip_file_1 subfolder/*";
$result = `$zip_cmd`;
```

Comment: Yes they can be run from a shell. I was hoping I could avoid learning PHP (due to lack of time, not because I have anything against it.)

Comment: It's not too bad, those 1-2 lines above can run the program, and you need another half-dozen lines to get the variables you passed to the PHP page.